# Anyway to shorten it?

Tags: vb.net

Hi I'm new to programming. Is there any way to shorten my program?

```
Private Sub ComboBox10_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox10.SelectedIndexChanged

        If ComboBox9.Text = "Power" Then

            If ComboBox8.Text = "Cable" Then
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Black")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Brown")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Red")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("White")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Grey")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Vio")
            End If
End If

Private Sub ComboBox11_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox11.SelectedIndexChanged

        If ComboBox9.Text = "Power" Then

            If ComboBox8.Text = "Cable" Then
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Black")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Brown")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Red")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("White")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Grey")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Vio")
            End If
End If

Private Sub ComboBox12_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox12.SelectedIndexChanged

        If ComboBox9.Text = "Power" Then

            If ComboBox8.Text = "Cable" Then
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Black")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Brown")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Red")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("White")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Grey")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Vio")
            End If
End If

Private Sub ComboBox13_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox13.SelectedIndexChanged

        If ComboBox9.Text = "Power" Then

            If ComboBox8.Text = "Cable" Then
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Black")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Brown")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Red")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("White")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Grey")
                ComboBox11.Items.Add("Vio")
            End If
End If
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a review. These questions are better suited here http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com and to answer your question ***yes it can be shortened***

Comment: This question belongs on code review. SO is for programming _problems_.

Comment: @JeffMercado Pardon me?

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub ComboBox10_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox10.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox11.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox12.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox13.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox9.Text = "Power" AndAlso ComboBox8.Text = "Cable" Then
        ComboBox11.Items.Add(New String() {"Black", "Brown", "Red", "White", "Grey", "Vio"})
    End If
End Sub
```